# Vanishing of an exponential sum $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k e^{ik b_k}$ on sets of the form $\{ \alpha l : l = -m, \dots, m \}$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k e^{ik b_k}$ is an exponential sum with frequencies $b_k \in \mathbb R$ and coefficients $a_k \in \mathbb C$. Further, let $S(\alpha, m)$ be the set
$$
S(\alpha, m) = \{ \alpha l : l = -m, \dots, m-1, m \} \subset \mathbb R, \quad \alpha >0, \quad m \in \mathbb N.
$$
Assuming that $N$ is fixed, can I find $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,m$ such that if $f$ vanishes on $S(\alpha_1, m) \cup S(\alpha_1, m)$ then $f$ vanishes everywhere on the real line? The point is here that I fix $N$ but I want to choose $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,m$ independent of the coefficients $a_k$ and frequencies $b_k$.

Comment: A few things are unclear: Is $n$ and $N$ the same? I guess also it should vanish on $S(\alpha_1,m)\cup S(\alpha_2,m)$ and not twice $\alpha_1$, right? Also your function $f$ lies in $\mathbb{C}$ but all your sets are only real, right?

Comment: Note that as $f$ is holomorphic, vanishing everywhere on the real line implies already that $f=0$ everywhere